# Questions about a proof in Greenberg's Book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma :

> **Lemma ' :**
>   Suppose that $X$ is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module ($\Lambda =\mathbb Z_p[[T]]$) and that  $f(T)=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} a_i T^i\in \Lambda.$ Let $r=\mathrm{rank}_{\Lambda}(X) $  and $l=\min \{i\hspace{2mm}:\hspace{2mm}a_i\in\mathbb Z_p^*\}.$ Then  $$\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(X/f(T)X) \geq rl.\hspace{10mm}(*)$$
>   If $X$ is a torsion-free $\Lambda$-module, then equality holds.

The proof, according to Greenberg (http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/book.pdf, page 82) :

> **Proof :**
>   To prove $(*),$ we can obviously replace $X$ by the quotient module
>   $X/X_{\Lambda-tors}$
>   . So we can assume without loss of generality that $X$ is a torsion-free $\Lambda$-module. We can also clearly assume that $f(T)$ is not divisible by $p.$
>
> Now $X$ contains a $\Lambda$-submodule $Y$ which is free of rank $r$ over $\Lambda$. We have the exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow Y\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow Z\longrightarrow0$$
>   where $Z$ is a finitely generated, torsion $\Lambda$-module $^{(1)}.$
>   The snake lemma then gives an exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow  Z[f(T)]\longrightarrow   Y/f(T)Y \longrightarrow X/f(T)X \longrightarrow Z/f(T)Z\longrightarrow 0$$
>   By **lemma'** $ Y/f (T )Y$ is a free $\mathbb Z_p$-module of rank $rl$ $^{(2)}. $ 
>   Let $U$ denote the
>   $\mathbb Z_p$-torsion submodule of $Z.$ $^{(3)}$ Then $Z/U$ is a free $\mathbb Z_p$-module of finite rank. This implies that $Z [f(T) ]$ and $Z/f (T )Z$ have the same (finite) $\mathbb Z_p$
>   -rank. Thus we see that $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(X/f(T)X) = rl.$

1. Why he says "we can assume that $X$ is torsion-free $\Lambda$-module" and works with $X$ torsion module ? and why such  $Z$ exists ?
2. In $^{(2)}$ I don't understand why he works with this Lemma before completing his proof ?
3. In $^{(3)}$ I don't see why $Z/U$ is a free $\mathbb Z_p$-module of finite rank implies that $Z [f(T) ]$ and $Z/f (T )Z$ have the same (finite) $\mathbb Z_p$-rank.
4. Why if $X/f(T)X$ has a finite order then by **Lemma'** we have $r=0.$?

Please can someone clarify it for me. And thank you so; so much for any help

Comment: A few things: i) What is $Z[f(T)]$? ii) Use the structure theorem for finite modules over a PID. iii) I don't understand your 4th question

Comment: @user115654 ;Thank you so much, $Z[f(T)]=\{z\in Z\hspace{2mm}:\hspace{2mm}f(T).z=0\}.$

Comment: @user115654; 4th question is not related to the proof of Lemma

Comment: @user115654 ; the objective of the lemma is to show that $$X/f(T)X\hspace{2mm}\text{is finite}\Rightarrow r=\mathrm{rank}_{\Lambda}(X)=0.$$

Comment: Do you mean if $X/f(T)X$ has finite order, then $\text{rank}_\Lambda(X) = 0$? Also, what is $\mathbb{Z}_p$? There are at least 3 possible meanings here

Comment: Yes exactly $X/f(T)X$ has finite order implies $r=0$. And $\mathbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: Ah, well in that case my earlier remark about the structure theorem doesn't apply, since $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ isn't a PID. There are still a lot of things which are unclear to me - it doesn't make sense to refer to a lemma in its own proof. For your 1st question though, try comparing the ranks of $X/f(T)X$ and $X'/f(T)X'$, where $X' = X/\{\Lambda\text{-torsion}\}$

Comment: @user115654 ; I know $X'/f(T)X'\cong X/f(T)X$ and therefore $X$ can be replaced by $X'$ but the problem is why he works be $X$ with torsion as $\Lambda$-module ?

Comment: @user115654; This proof is here http://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/book.pdf, page 82.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the source, I agree that the proof is slightly confusing - there is (at least) one typo: when he claims that $Y/f(T)Y$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module of rank $rl$, he is using Lemma 2.2.3, not the present Lemma. However, you seem to be primarily interested in the application to question 4, i.e. why $|X/f(T)X| < \infty$ implies $r = 0$. This is just because if $X/f(T)X$ finite order, then it has rank $0$, so by this Lemma, $rl = 0$, but $l > 0$ in the case of application, so $r = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand why $|X/f(T)X|<\infty$ implies that : $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(X/f(T)X)=0  $ ? can you explain this thing.

Comment: What is your definition of $\text{rank}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}$?

Comment: My definition is :  $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(M)=\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(M/M_{tors-\mathbb Z_p}).$

Comment: And how do you define $\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(M/M_{\mathbb Z_p-tors})$?

Comment: Since $M/M_{tors-\mathbb Z_p}$ is torsion free $\mathbb Z_p$ -module; we have  $M/M_{tors-\mathbb Z_p}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}m_{i}\mathbb Z_p;$ and so the $\mathbb Z_p$-rank is $r$.

Comment: So is it possible for something of finite order to contain a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Dear user115654, I do not see how I can use it to prove that :$\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbb Z_p}(X/f(T)X)=0.$

Comment: If $M$ has finite order, then so does $M/M_\text{tors}$. If $M/M_\text{tors}$ has rank > 0, then it contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is infinite. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes. Now I understand, thank you so, so much sir.

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel your question was answered, you may want to mark it as such (to avoid staying in the unanswered queue)

Comment: I want to understand the proof of Lemma.(if you can explain it to me I will be very happy, exactly questions 2 and 3) and thank you again.

Comment: Unfortunately I have neither the time nor energy to do that right now. Perhaps someone else familiar with the book can - in any case, I wish you good luck in understanding Iwasawa theory

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)